# GtkLabel segmentation fault

Tags: gtk, segmentation-fault

I want to use use-markup, but it does not seem to work. Without it, everything works fine.

```
label_markup = g_object_new(GTK_TYPE_LABEL, "wrap", TRUE, "use-markup", TRUE, "label", "<span font_desc=\"Courier New Bold 16\">Courier-span>");
```

Could this be caused by having the wrong development packages installed? I'm doing the 2.0 tutorials, but accidentally installed libgtk3.0-dev and then updated my repositories. Now it has been removed?!

---

**EDIT FOR ANYONE ELSE READING THIS:** The example is from the book "The Official GNOME 2 Developer's Guide" and can be found on page 114-115 - I just shortened it. Problem is that the compiler does not complain, you just won't be able to run the program without ever knowing why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `NULL` at the end of your `g_object_new()` call. Without it, there is no way of knowing how many arguments you passed, which causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: This was it! I tried it and it worked perfectly. You are my hero.. thank you so much. The bug is actually in the source code of the book and it's a mean one because the compiler does not complain at all..

Comment: That book is fairly old. I'd recommend using a newer book to learn Gnome programming - for example, the 10-minute tutorials on developer.gnome.org.

Comment: And, it's actually a bug that the compiler doesn't complain - `g_object_new()` should be declared with the attribute `G_GNUC_NULL_TERMINATED`. It isn't, I looked: [gobject.h](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gobject/gobject.h) Would you like to report that on bugzilla.gnome.org?